# using map2 to filter through data

Tags: r, filter, purrr

I have a dataset with several numerical variables, and I am checking that the observed values do not go over or below a specific range.

I have identified which variables in my dataset are outside the range, and now I want to use purrr to filter my data using the variable name that is outside range(.x) and -for example- the expected lower range (.y).

This is the tibble I created with the affected variables and the expected minimum values:

```
    x <- tibble(
    vbl.name = c("dbp","plat", "plat.b", "fib", "bili", "osat"),
    observed.min = c(25, 33, 33, 0.1, 0, 0.84),
    expected.min = c(50, 50, 50, 1, 1, 47))
```

My data is large with the following dimensions: (647, 97).

What I am doing is:

```
    map2_df(.x = x$vbl_name), 
            .y = x$expected_min, 
            .f = ~{my_data %>% filter(.x < .y)})
```

I get the error that the result must be of length 647 not 6.
I don't know how to fix this or if I am using `map2` the right way?

Comment: For the data you have shared what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

As this question currently stands, it's very difficult understanding what is happening here.  One part of the question states,  `"I am checking that the observed values do not go over or below a specific range."`

There is likely a mistake in the following part of the question:

```
 `.x = x$vbl_name),`
```

Most likely this line of code should read:

```
 `x <- x$observed.min`
```

If this correction is true, then this question begins to make more sense.  The question further states: `I want to use` purrr `to filter my data`.

The purrr package is used for `functional programming` - which is an advanced topic in R.  `Functional programming` is designed to eliminate `loops` in the code.   As things stand, there doesn't appear to be any reason to have any loop to answer this question.  Therefore there is no need to use `purrr` for filtering.

The `filter()` function from the `dplyr` package is designed specifically for the purpose of filtering.  This code is from the question. This code incorrectly uses the `dplyr` filter function with some `purrr` features.  This `pipe` won't work because the filter returns a `logical` value.

```
my_data %>% filter(.x < .y)}
```

The line of code above can be changed to simply `filter (x < y)` using the `dplyr` filter without using the `purrr` features.

Below is a reproducible data frame that represents data similar to the non- reproducible data shown with the question.

```
df <- structure(list(
                 vbl.name = c("dbp","plat", "plat.b", "fib", "bili", "osat"), 
                 obs.min = c(15,5,90,5,80,80),
                 exp.min = c(75,30,10,25,40,20)),
                 .Names = c("vbl.name", "obs.min", "exp.min"),
                 row.names = c(NA, 6L),
                 class = "data.frame")
```

Shown below is the code used to `filter (x < y )`.  And the resulting filtered output.

```
df %>% filter(obs.min < exp.min)

    A data.frame: 3 × 3
vbl.name    obs.min    exp.min
<chr>       <dbl>      <dbl>
dbp          15         75
plat          5         30
fib           5         25
```